# Add students to a table with stored procedures, and check if the parameter is false or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a `Student` table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
  studentID int,
  firstname varchar(100),
  lastname varchar(100),
  gender varchar(6),
  streetAdress varchar(100),
  zipcode int,
  city varchar(100),
  country varchar(100),
  birthdate varchar(100),
  studentType varchar(100),
  primary key (studentID)
);

insert into Students values(5341,'Erik','Han','Man','Alléstigen 13',1223,'District 13','France','1945-01-06','Program');
```

Now I know that you can insert it like this but how would I do that with stored procedures, where input to the procedure is  `studentID`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `streetAdress`,
`zipcode`, `city`, `country`, `birthdate` and `studentType`. The other thing is, can I make it so it checks if the inputs that are given are false or if the user already exists and if any of this is true, it should exit without adding anything.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddStudents  @studentID, @firstname, @lastname, @gender, @streetAdress,
@zipcode, @city, @country, @birthdate, @studentType   
...     
GO;
```

Do I just put

```
insert into Students values (@studentID, @firstname, @lastname, @gender, @streetAdress,
    @zipcode, @city, @country, @birthdate, @studentType)
```

Inside of the procedure and then have

```
EXEC AddStudents @studentID = 5341, @firstname = 'Erik', @lastname = 'Han', @gender = 'Man', @streetAdress = 'Alléstigen 13', @zipcode = 1223, @city = 'District 13', @country = 'France', @birthdate = '1945-01-06', @birthdate = 'Program';
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server manager

Comment: If you want to prohibit duplicate records, which is what it sounds like, you can either put logic inside the stored proc to check before the insert.  You could also send back an appropriate error_code if necessary.

Comment: Why would you store a birthdate as a `varchar` when SQL Server has a `date` datatype? That is asking for trouble - you should see how many questions on SO are about people trying to resolves issues caused by storing dates as strings.

Comment: If you look at the [official `insert` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (which should always be your first port of call), you will see that you can specify which columns to insert, not only, but its recommended to always list the columns when inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to solving your problem there are a lot of things you can do to improve your code:

1. Use a `date` datatype for your date of birth.
2. Don't use an `int` for a zip code. If you don't already, you will eventually require a letter or a space.
3. Don't manually assign the `studentId`, use an `identity` column. Otherwise you will run into id maintenance/duplicate problems. If you also have a human `studentId` then store that as another column, keeping the primary key id as an identity.
4. Always fully specify the columns you are inserting - this is the recommended way to write an insert statement and will save you problems later if you change the definition of your table.

Finally to solve the problem you asked about, specify the columns to insert in your insert statement (see the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), and use a where clause to prevent adding a duplicate. I've used the `studentId` column as a simple example - but as you should really be using an `identity` column you won't be able to use that for you duplicate check. Instead you would use name + date of birth (or similar).

You can validate the parameters according to any rules you like and return without attempting an insert.

Returning a unique result code is a simple way for your calling code to know whether a successful insert occurred or an error. You assign the result as `exec @MyResult = AddStudents {parameter list here}` where `@MyResult` is defined in the calling context.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE AddStudents
    (
      @studentID int
      , @firstname varchar(100)
      , @lastname varchar(100)
      , @gender varchar(6)
      , @streetAdress varchar(100)
      , @zipcode int
      , @city varchar(100)
      , @country varchar(100)
      , @birthdate varchar(100)
      , @studentType varchar(100)
    )
    as
    begin
      set nocount on;

      -- Add parameter validation as required e.g.
      if coalesce(@firstname,'') = '' return 98;

      insert into Students (studentID, firstname, lastname, gender, streetAdress, zipcode, city, country, birthdate, studentType)
        select @studentID, @firstname, @lastname, @gender, @streetAdress,
          @zipcode, @city, @country, @birthdate, @studentType
        -- use the where clause to see whether a duplicate student already exists
        where not exists (
          select 1
          from Students
          where studentID = @studentID
          -- Add any other checks required to avoid a duplicate
        )

      -- Check the return result to see whether a new student record was added or not
      return case when @@rowcount = 1 then 0 else 99 end;
    end
    go
```

Comment: Hi just a follow up why do I get a `Invalid column name 'firstname'` in the `if coalesce(firstName,'') = '' return 98;`

Comment: @TOm sorry it should have been `coalesce(@firstName,'')` since its validating a parameter.

Comment: oh changed it, before you said anything just wanted to make sure is it not  `@firstname` and not `@firstName`

Comment: @TOm whatever you called it :) SQL Server is not case sensitive anyway.